# Does Weibo have an v2 search api?

Tags: weibo, sinaweibo

I'm trying to build a sina app which will have capabilities of searching statuses based on key word, geo location, date etc...

I cannot find an api which supports what I'm trying to do.

I am aware they have a v1 api which does what I want but it is legacy and no longer accepting apps.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that weibo has removed most of the content search api functionality in v2 of the api.

The api calls that are currently supported are listed here: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3_V2/en#Search_API

Content search is labeled only for legacy applications that have good standing.